# Obtener Array de un Objeto - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

me puedan ayudar,
tengo un array que es el siguiente, quiero agarrar todo el segundo json del campo data todo sus valores

**Array: Series**

```
    [
  {
    "type": "column",
    "name": "Monto",
    "categoryDef": "meses",
    "fillOpacity": 0,
    "order": 2,
    "data": [
      4347481.1,
      681002.1,
      495996.2
    ],
    "format": {
      "type": "number",
      "mode": ".0-0"
    },
    "yAxis": 0
  },
  {
    "type": "spline",
    "name": "Transacciones",
    "categoryDef": "meses",
    "fillOpacity": 0,
    "order": 1,
    "data": [
      13332,
      2489,
      1589
    ],
    "format": {
      "type": "number",
      "mode": ".0-0"
    },
    "yAxis": 1
  }
]
```

Quisiera obtener el segundo json

**

```
 {
        "type": "spline",
        "name": "Transacciones",
        "categoryDef": "meses",
        "fillOpacity": 0,
        "order": 1,
        "data": [
          13332,
          2489,
          1589
        ],
        "format": {
          "type": "number",
          "mode": ".0-0"
        },
        "yAxis": 1
      }
```

**

He realizado lo siguiente para obtenerlos: y en la consula me sale el siguiente error: **error TS2493: Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '1'.**

```
let series2;
series2=(series[1]);
series2= series2.data;
```

**Adjunto el print del error: Cuando doy clic para ver donde es el error me vota aqui:**

```
  series2=(series[1]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**aqui habia un codigo donde he visto por el console que concatena todo las serie de data, pero como haria para que obtenga la serie 1**

```
series.forEach((s:any)=>data=data.concat(s.data).filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: Disculpa, ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta? Es un poco difícil entender la redacción. O al menos no entiendo realmente qué es lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: Por tu código, estás accediendo bien a la propiedad data del segundo JSON. Tu problema ha de ser al acceder a `this.yAxis[1]`,

Comment: @eduardo edite mi pregunta, quisiera obtener el segundo json los datos del array data que son 10,20,30

Answer (score 2):

```js
const series = [
    {
        "type": "spline",
        "name": "Transacciones",
        "categoryDef": "meses",
        "data": [
            1,
            9,
            50
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "spline",
        "name": "Transacciones",
        "categoryDef": "meses",
        "data": [
            10,
            20,
            30
        ]
    }
]
console.log(series[1].data)
```

Con ese código la respuesta es la que tu buscas.

```
[LOG]: [10, 20, 30]
```

Si quieres el JSON completo bastaría con.

```js
console.log(series[1])
```

Obtendrias como resultado

```
  [LOG]: {
  "type": "spline",
  "name": "Transacciones",
  "categoryDef": "meses",
  "data": [
    10,
    20,
    30
  ]
}
```

Comment: Mauricio, eso también hice, pero me arroja este error.

Comment: Mauricio me arroja este error: error TS2493: Tuple type '[]' of length '0' has no element at index '1'.

Comment: Seguramente tu problema sea como estas almacenando el Json en la variable que lo tiene almacenado, seria bueno que nos compartas como lo recibes y lo almacenas

Comment: he editado mi pregunta , adjunte la captura del error y donde me indica el error

Comment: He visto la captura y de ser posible me gustaría que también compartieras el contenido que recibe la función al momento de ser llamada ya que me parece que tu código esta correcto

Comment: mira en la captura hay un foreach lo que hace es juntar todo los data o se podría hacer lo. Mismo pero obtener solo la segunda parte?

Comment: Josue
series.forEach((s:any)=>data=data.concat(s.data).filter(Boolean));